# How do I get an int from a string that may contain dates in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, regex, validation, date

I have to take a string from a third-party tool which contains an integer, stripping the int, and using it to join on a local table. I am using [Pinal Dave's udf_GetNumeric function](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/14/sql-server-get-numeric-value-from-alpha-numeric-string-udf-for-get-numeric-numbers-only/) which works great for `I worked on ticket no. 123456 for a long time`, but now users are entering things like `5/9/2016 ticket 123456 was closed as duplicate`, which returns `5092016123456`. I could modify the search pattern to only look at 5 or more consecutive numbers since our ID column is > 9999, but sql doesn't understand `([0-9]{5,})`. I can't install CLR to use full regex, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you assume that all numbers are separated with space from the text? If you split the text from spaces into separate rows and take a row that contains only numbers?

Comment: Your question isnt clear. Show us some data and desire output. What is the logic you want apply? Why you mean Sql doesnt undestand regexpresion? Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Sorry for the awkward wording. Basically, I have "here is a string 123456 blah blah blah 5/09/2016" and I want to get the 123456. Yes, I guess I can assume numbers will be separated by a space, so I can try that. Sql does understand regex, but it's a limited subset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I could modify the search pattern to only look at 5 or more
>   consecutive numbers since our ID column is > 9999, but sql doesn't
>   understand ([0-9]{5,}). I can't install CLR

You can modify the search pattern to use `%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%` then. That will find strings of 5 consecutive integers. e.g. As below.

```
WITH T(Notes)
     AS (SELECT 'I worked on ticket no 123456.  for a long time ')
SELECT *,
       SUBSTRING(Notes, PatIdx, Length)
FROM   T
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', Notes)) CA(PatIdx)
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', SUBSTRING(Notes + ' ', PatIdx, 8000)) - 1) CA2(Length)
```

Comment: Thanks, Martin. This would work for now, but the 123456 is an identity column and will eventually have more than 5 or 6 numbers, but that is long enough in the future that I probably don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Well if there are 6 consecutive numbers a pattern that finds 5 will find 6. But having found the start point you should probably look to find the first non integer from that point on. Will edit.

Comment: Thanks! This works too and is less overkill than my answer.

Comment: @DavidFrodin - It also doesn't rely on the numbers being surrounded by spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Using JamesZ's suggestion to split on the spaces, I repurposed an old function that I use elsewhere.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf_CreateVarcharTableFromCsv]
    (
      @VarcharCsv VARCHAR(4000) ,
      @Seperator VARCHAR(5) = NULL
    )
RETURNS @VarcharTable TABLE
    (
      VarcharIndex VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    )
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @localVarcharIndexList VARCHAR(4000);  
        DECLARE @localSeperator VARCHAR(5);  
        SET @localVarcharIndexList = @VarcharCsv;
        SET @localSeperator = @Seperator;
        IF @localSeperator IS NULL
            SET @localSeperator = ',';

        /*****************************************************************************************
        Parse CSVs into tables with CTE
        http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-2005-common-table-expressions/
        *****************************************************************************************/
        IF @localVarcharIndexList IS NOT NULL
            BEGIN
                WITH    VarcharCsv ( i, j, VarcharIndex )
                          AS ( SELECT   i = 1 ,
                                        VarcharIndex = CHARINDEX(@localSeperator,
                                                              @localVarcharIndexList
                                                              + @localSeperator) ,
                                        SUBSTRING(@localVarcharIndexList, 1,
                                                  CHARINDEX(@localSeperator,
                                                            @localVarcharIndexList
                                                            + @localSeperator)
                                                  - 1)
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   i = j + 1 ,
                                        j = CHARINDEX(@localSeperator,
                                                      @localVarcharIndexList
                                                      + @localSeperator, j + 1) ,
                                        SUBSTRING(@localVarcharIndexList,
                                                  j + 1,
                                                  CHARINDEX(@localSeperator,
                                                            @localVarcharIndexList
                                                            + @localSeperator,
                                                            j + 1) - ( j + 1 ))
                               FROM     VarcharCsv
                               WHERE    CHARINDEX(@localSeperator,
                                                  @localVarcharIndexList
                                                  + @localSeperator, j + 1) <> 0
                             )
                    INSERT  INTO @VarcharTable
                            SELECT  VarcharIndex
                            FROM    VarcharCsv
                    OPTION  ( MAXRECURSION 500 );
            END;
        RETURN; 
    END;
```

And it can be used like this for my requirements:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    [tvf_CreateVarcharTableFromCsv]('here is a string 123456 blah blah blah 5/09/2016"',
                                        ' ')
WHERE   LEN(VarcharIndex) > 5
        AND ISNUMERIC(VarcharIndex) = 1
```